# Arduino cannot press button only ones when I want the green LED to do -30 delay (look description)

Tags: button, arduino, project, led

This is a game that i made called STOP IT. So every time I press the button when the green light blinks the delay goes -30 so it goed faster every time I click the button. The problem is is that i can just hold the button and it doesn't work when i only click ones on it. So i have to hold it to be able to let it work.

So please help me!

ps someone told me that i had to work with mills but I don't really get what that means.

This is my project layout in tinkercad
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH632.png

This is the code

```
int ledPins[] = {9,10,11,12,13};
int buttonPin = 8;
int ledState = LOW;
int buttonState = LOW;  
int tijd = 1000;
String start;
bool yn = false;



void setup() {            
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {     
  pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);      
  }
}


void loop() { 

    if (Serial.available() > 0) {

  start = Serial.readString();
    
    if(start == "start")
    {
      yn = true;
    }
  }
  
  while(yn){
                          
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);   
    CheckIfCorrect();         
    delay(tijd);            
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);   
      
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
          
        start = Serial.readString();
          
        if(start == "stop"){
          yn = false;
        }
     }
  }
  
  delay(1); 
  }
                
}

void CheckIfCorrect(){
  
  ledState = digitalRead(ledPins[2]);         
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.println(buttonState);            
  
  if (buttonState == HIGH && ledState == HIGH) {  
    Serial.println("Good job!!!");
    Serial.println(tijd);

    if (tijd > 199) {
      tijd  = tijd - 30; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what `millis` are then you should start reading the Arduino documentation.

Answer (score 0):

hope you're doing fine, there are too many impossibles in your code to help ya get it going, so I made one for you, Enjoy!

```
// copied from stack overflow question, modified by Edgar Wideman, free for all!

int ledPins[] = {9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
int buttonPin = 8;
int ledState = LOW;
int buttonState = LOW;
int litLED = 0;
int tijd = 1000;
String start;
bool yn = false;
bool ledIsLit = false;
bool buttonPressed = false;

unsigned long delayTime = 0;
unsigned long blinkDelayTime = 0;
int blinkDelay = 300;



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); // Use INPUT_PULLUP to use builtin pullup resistor.
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}


void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    start = Serial.readString();

    if (start == "start")
    {
      yn = true;
    }
  }

  while (yn) {

    if (millis() - delayTime > tijd) {
      delayTime = millis();
      blinkDelayTime = millis();
      int lastLitLED = litLED; 
      litLED = random(0, 4); // get a random number between 0 and 4.
      if(lastLitLED == litLED){ // just add plus one if number is same as the last.
        litLED++;
      }
      lastLitLED = litLED;
      digitalWrite(ledPins[litLED], HIGH);
      Serial.print("LED: ");
      Serial.println(litLED);
      while (true) { // This will be looped until escaped after blinkDelay amount millis.
        if (millis() - blinkDelayTime > blinkDelay) { // check if time delay has passed
          digitalWrite(ledPins[litLED], LOW);
          buttonPressed = false;
          break; // break out of the while loop.
        }
        bool button = true;
        if(!buttonPressed)
        button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
//        button = !button; //Uncomment if using pullup resistor.
        if (button && (litLED == 2)) {  // Button press was correct.
          buttonPressed = true;
          Serial.println("Good job!!!");
          if (delayTime > 199) { // subtract 30 millis if correct.
            tijd = tijd - 30;
          }
        }
        else if (button && (litLED != 2)) { // Button press was incorrect.
          buttonPressed = true;
          Serial.println("WRONG!!!");
          tijd = 1000; // reset game.
        }
      }
    }


    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      start = Serial.readString();
      if (start == "stop") {
        yn = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Created this in like 10 min, please don't hate on me for unideal coding... you may optimize to your own desire.